# Display the uploaded image in another element

Tags: filepond

How I can get the image that the user just uploaded to display in another element on the same page? I'm using the `storeAsFile` property within the filePond options.

As note, I'm currently displaying the image with ImagePreview plugin within the filepond input instance, but i want to show this image on another part of the page. Hope i'm being clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution,

```
pondPhoto.on('addfile', (error, file) => {
  // this object contains the file info
  console.log(file.file)
  
  // you can construct a blob object
  const imageSrc = URL.createObjectURL(file.file)

  // then you may attach it to any image in your DOM
  document.querySelector('img').setAttribute('src', imageSrc)
})
```